# Embed a file with LuaTeX and hyperref and setting AFRelationship

Tags: hyperref, luatex, pdf-a, embedfile

I want to embed files in a pdf. I do need a /AFRelationship entry in the PDF because this is mandated by PDF/A. The minimal example below works for pdfTeX. It also works with LuaTeX when `hyperref` is disabled. However it does not work with hyperref and LuaTeX.

#### MWE

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{embedfile}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\embedfile[afrelationship={/Source}]{\jobname.tex}

\begin{document}
Text
\end{document}
```

#### MWE output

produces

```
<</Type/Filespec/F(testbrief.tex)/AFRelationship\376\377\000/\000S\000o\000u\000r\000c\000e/EF<</F 1 0 R>>>>
```

This throws a validation error in Acrobat DC's Preflight for PDF/A3-b:
[image]
With `hyperref` disabled I get

```
<</Type/Filespec/F(testbrief.tex)/AFRelationship/Source/EF<</F 1 0 R>>>>
```

which passes validation.

#### Question

Since I need luatex for font handling and hyperref for links and metadata this is a problem. How to get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

A corrected version of embedfile has been uploaded to ctan. The patch is no longer needed. The entry looks now, without the patch,  like this

```
<</Type/Filespec/F(a.tex)/AFRelationship/Source/EF<</F 1 0 R>>>>
```

### Old Answer.

It is a bug. Embedfile shouldn't try to convert this value.

Try this patch

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3pdf}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\pdf_uncompress:
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{embedfile}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\EmFi@embedfile
 {\EmFi@convert\EmFi@afrelationship\EmFi@@afrelationship}
 {\let\EmFi@@afrelationship\EmFi@afrelationship}{}{\fail}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\embedfile[afrelationship={/Source}]{embedtest.tex}
\begin{document}
Text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. I see there is already an [issue about this](https://github.com/ho-tex/embedfile/issues/1#issuecomment-606501921).

Comment: @tanGIS the fix has been uplpaded to ctan.